# Arrange array elements positive negative zero

Tags: java, arrays

How can I place zeros inside the array, I have rearranged positive and negative numbers but how to do for zeros, Below is my code.

```
int i = 0;
int arr[] = { 3, 7,-12, 8, -1, 6, -6, 5, -2};
int j = arr.length - 1;
while (true) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
        ++i; 
    }
    if (arr[j] < 0) {
        --j;
    }
    if (i > j) 
        break; 
    if (arr[i] < 0 && arr[j] > 0) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

for (int j2 = 0; j2 < arr.length; j2++) {
            System.out.print(arr[j2]);
        }
```

If I place zero in the array, it doesn't show any output. otherwise it gives  `37586-1-6-12-2` I am looking for solution with minimum comparisons.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more?

Comment: We don't know what this code is supposed to do. And it doesn't output anything, so whether the array contains 0 or not, you'll never have any output. It looks like you want to sort an array. Use Arrays.sort().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which solve the problem. I added similar part of existing algorithm (to original I made little changes, now it check `>=0` instead `>0`). In the second part I do the same for positive and `0` numbers.

```
int i = 0;
int arr[] = {0, 3, 7, -12, 8, -1, 0,  6, -6, 5, -2, 0, -1, 0};

int j = arr.length - 1;
while (true) {
    if (arr[i] >= 0) {
        ++i;
    }
    if (arr[j] < 0) {
        --j;
    }

    if (i > j)
        break;
    if (arr[i] < 0 && arr[j] >= 0) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

// The second part for positives and 0-s, starting for [0, j] (j is not changed)
i = 0;

while (true) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
        ++i;
    }
    if (arr[j] == 0) {
        --j;
    }

    if (i > j)
        break;

    if (arr[i] == 0 && arr[j] > 0) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

for (int anArr : arr) {
    System.out.print(anArr + ", ");
}
```

The result is:

```
5, 3, 7, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, -6, -2, -1, -1, -12,
```